# Error settings `hostname_configuration` when retrieving azure api management resource with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I am experiencing an error when I attempt to retrieve an Azure API Management service using the following terraform.

```
data "azurerm_api_management" "foundations-apim" {
  name                = "${var.foundations-apimanagement-name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.foundations-resource-group-name}"
}
```

> Error setting `hostname_configuration`: Invalid address to set :
>   []string{"hostname_configuration", "0", "portal", "0",
>   "default_ssl_binding"}

Terraform v0.11.11

provider.azurerm v1.20.0

Comment: Can you try to query it using the REST API Explorer?  Do you get the same error? https://resources.azure.com/

Comment: @Jamie, I don't get any error when I am viewing the API Management instance via resources.azure.com